# Powershell capture group - insert some text after the matching line

Tags: regex, powershell, replace

**I am trying to insert a line with powershell statement into multiple script files.**

**The content of the files are like these (3 cases)**

```
"param($installPath)"
```

- no CRLF characters, only 1st line

```
"param($installPath)`r`n`"
```

- with CRLF characters, no 2nd line

```
"param($installPath)`r`n`some text on the second line"
```

- with CRLF characters, non-empty 2nd line

**I want to insert some text (poweshell statement in the second line `'r'n$myvar = somethingelse`) so it is immediately below the first line appending 'r'n characters to the first line if they don't exist**

```
"param($installPath)`r`nmyvar = somethingelse"
```

- ADD CRLF character first to the 1st line and ADD $myvar = somethingelse on the 2nd line

```
"param($installPath)`r`n`$myvar = somethingelse"
```

- ONLY ADD "$myvar = somethingelse" on the 2nd line, since CRLF already exists (no need to add the ending `r`n)

```
"param($installPath)`r`n`$myvar = somethingelse`r`n`some text on the second line"**
```

- ADD "$myvar = somethingelse'r'n" on the 2nd line (CRLF already exists on the first line) and APPEND CRLF to it so the existing text on the second line will move to 3rd line.

I was trying to use this regular expression:
"^param(.+)(?:(`r`n`))"
and this replacement, but with no success ($1 is the first capture group, $2 is non capture group which I ignore even if something is found and I explicitly add CRLF after $1 capture group)
 "$1`r`n`myvar = somethingelse"

Thanks,

Rad

Answer (score 1):

The following use of `-replace` seems to match your requirements

```
$content = "param(some/path)"
#$content = "param(some/path)`r`n"  
#$content = "param(some/path)`r`n`some text on the second line"

$content = $content -replace "^(param\(.+\))(?:\r\n$)?",
        ( '$1' + "`r`nmyvar = somethingelse" )

Write-Host "`n$content"
```

Note that references to capture groups have to be in single quotes.

The optional, uncaptured `(?:\r\n$)` group ensures that CRLF is removed if there is nothing, i.e. the end of string `$`, following it.

**Edit**

If what follows `param` is not known, the following regex could be used instead.
It uses `[^\r\n]` to capture characters that are not newlines.

```
"^(param[^\r\n]*)(?:\r\n$)?"
```

Comment: Thanks it works if you use "(" and ")" as anchors, but what if it something else after "param" word (which is the only word known) and that you can anchor with ^(param). So when I use "^(param.+)(?:\r\n$)?" the replacement is not working. If you could try to handle this case it would be great. Thanks.

Comment: I suppose this is not a multiline operation (Does "$" actually represents the end of the file or row. So is the non-captured \r\n character at the end of the first line or at the and of the file -in this case the end of the string simulating a file content). Can you please explain how Regex engine analyses this Regex you suggested

Comment: @Rad. My regex assumes that there is only one param and it is at the start of the file. Is that correct?

Comment: @Rad.  Posted edit. Also, to answer your earlier question, the `$` matched by `(?:\r\n$)?` represents the end of the file. BTW `param.+` doesn't work because `.` matches `\r`.